# File.Move / File.Copy nothing happening

Tags: c#, file-copying, file-move

I am trying to write a code to move (or copy) some files into some folders (Actually to categorize those files by their extensions.)

Everything in the code works fine (Scanning folder and discovering files, extracting their extensions and creating folders and naming them with extensions) except when it is supposed to move/copy files into corresponding folder. It does nothing regarding this task.

Here is the code (In case you need files and folders to test my code, a link to a zipped file containing some sample file & folder is provided at the end of the question.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ramezanian_VCS_SysProg_Course
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            /* string variables to hold working directory path and 
                an array of filenames and a list of extensions. */
            String ThisPath = @"E:\HDR1";
            String[] ThisFiles = null;
            List<string> NotDottedExtensionContainer = new List<string>();

            //Getting filevnames with their full path.
            ThisFiles = Directory.GetFiles(ThisPath);

            /* Creating a text log file and also a list of file extensions while trimming and capitalizing them
              like this: file.txt -> .txt -> TXT */
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter ThisLogFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(ThisPath, "Log_File.txt")))
                //
                foreach (String _F in ThisFiles)
                    {
                        NotDottedExtensionContainer.Add(Path.GetExtension(_F).TrimStart('.').ToUpper());
                        ThisLogFile.WriteLine(_F);
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw; //In case something oes wrong.
            }

            UInt16 Temp_CountOfExtensions = 0; //A temporary variable to count how many extensions are there and so
            // how many folders will be created then.

            ThisPath = @"E:\HDR1\";
            //Making a distinct collection of unique extensions...
            IEnumerable<string> UniqueExtensionsCollection = NotDottedExtensionContainer.Distinct();
            foreach (String TempItem1 in UniqueExtensionsCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(TempItem1);
                //Then creating based on that distinct list.
                Directory.CreateDirectory(ThisPath + TempItem1);
                Temp_CountOfExtensions++;
            }
            foreach (String TempItem2 in UniqueExtensionsCollection)
            {
                foreach (String TempItem3 in ThisFiles)
                {
                    //This compares each file extension with subfolder names...
                    if (Path.GetExtension(TempItem3).TrimStart('.').ToUpper() == TempItem2)
                    {
                        //... To move them into their right place...
                        File.Move(TempItem3, ThisPath + TempItem2 + Path.GetFileName(TempItem3));
                    }
                    //...but nothing happens!
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total of {0} subfolders were created in {1}.",Temp_CountOfExtensions, ThisPath);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output (All folders are created successfully with desired names.):

[Link to output screenshot](https://fastupload.io/WnLtqamlrGeaoj5/file)

A sample working directory to test the code: [CLICK HERE](https://fastupload.io/dUoLsc9zA5eWI4x/file)

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint at the `File.Move` line and run in the debugger? Do you ever fall into the if block? If not, maybe the value of `Path.GetExtension(TempItem3).TrimStart('.').ToUpper()` or `TempItem2` isn't what you'd expect

Comment: Furthermore, strongly recommend using something like `String.Equals(Path.GetExtension(TempItem3).TrimStart('.'), TempItem2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` rather than working with cases on your own. It's a very common vector for bugs (and it's less performant, too)

Comment: @Luke Using breakpoints shows that it passes if-condition successfully by true value and File.Move() is being loaded with correct values.

Answer (score 3):

You need a slash between the extension folder and the file

```
File.Move(TempItem3, ThisPath + TempItem2 + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(TempItem3));
```

As long as the second path doesn't start with a backslash you can just use Path.Combine for this stuff too,

```
File.Move(TempItem3, Path.Combine(ThisPath, TempItem2, Path.GetFileName(TempItem3)));
```

Comment: whats that supposed to mean `As long as the second path doesn't start with a backslash…`

Comment: @RandRandom `Path.Combine(@"C:\folder\", @"\folder2")` returns `\folder2` without combining it with the first path, the leading slash is a "relative path" and Path.Combine treats it special for some reason. If you type `Path.Combine(@"C:\folder\", @"D:\folder2")` it also just returns the second path by itself without trying to combine it with the first path.